# How to solve non-fractional limits like $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{(\ln5) \div (1+\ln x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{(\ln5) \div (1+\ln x)}$. I am trying to figure out how to solve this, but I only know how to handle limits when they can be made into fractions. Is there some way I can do that here, or should I try something else?

This is a homework problem, and I don't need a complete answer, but I'd appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We asked to evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}}$ which can also be written as $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{\ln(x){\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}}}$. Using a few other rules, you can get to the following expression
$$ e^{\ln(5) \cdot \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+\ln(x)} } $$

Now I will leave the details to you but as a hint, remind yourself of L'hospital's rule.

And finally, you can show:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}} = 5 $$

Comment: Exactly, that is why I mentioned 'I will leave the details to you'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exponential $$\exp(\ln f(x))= f(x)$$and the fact that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} e^{f(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)}$$ then use natural log properties

Answer (score 2):

Let $P = x^{\frac {\ln (5)} {1 + \ln (x)}}.$ Then $\ln P = \frac {\ln (5)\ln (x)} {1 + \ln (x)}.$  As $x \rightarrow \infty,$ $\ln P$ takes $\frac {\infty} {\infty}$ form. So by L'Hospital rule we have $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \ln P = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac {\ln (5) \cdot \ln (x)} {1 + \ln (x)} = \ln (5) \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac {\frac 1 x} {\frac 1 x} = \ln (5).$$ This shows that $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} P = e^{\ln(5)} = 5.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard method is to write it with $e$:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\ln(x)\ln(\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)})}$

Comment: I think the question is asking for $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{\ln(5)}{1+\ln(x)}}$

Comment: True, but does not change anything.

Comment: True, except it is only a coincidence that it does not change the final answer in this case. Clearly, $1 + \ln(x) \neq \ln(1+x)$

Comment: @Rob It does not matter, about the final answer anyways, but how to approach the problem, and it is still the same method.

Comment: That is very true! I hope educational systems adapt to that method. Because as soon as you make the first mistake, the marks are deducted, even if you have the right approach, which is more important than getting the right answer.